# C# - Is there a way to use reflection for generalizing Edit views of every possible view model of ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm thinking of generalizing all Edit views scaffolded by the MVC because they are pretty much the same except for the properties of the model they are editing.

I managed to do the same thing for Index and Details views but I have no idea how to generate the  tags having only the model's property name that I need an editor for.

I've seen examples of similar things being done using complex custom tag helpers but I cannot seem to adapt them to my case.

Basically I need to turn

```
<input asp-for="Email" class="form-control mb-4" />
```

into something like this

```
<input asp-for="@emailPropertyNameString" class="form-control mb-4" />
```

but, as tested, string or property info will not do.

What options do I have in front of me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is not recommended to use reflection for Edit view which may hit performance issue.

If you insist on this requirement, you could try code below:

```
@model dynamic

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Model.GetType();
        <form asp-action="EditBook">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var propValue = @prop.GetValue(@Model, null);
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@prop.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@propValue" name="@prop.Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@prop.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I was doing the same thing but for some reason my code did not work out like yours. Thanks a lot.

Also, I know using reflection will probably have some impact on the performance but performance is not the main task at this moment of the development.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If performance is an issue you could always cache the results of the reflection so they come back instantly the second time.  You just have to be sure you don't cache any values related to a specific instances otherwise you'll leak data from one user to another (an immutable type would be preferred for this reason).  I've cached reflected model data for dynamic form rendering often with great success.  The one caveat being if the form elements themselves change between users viewing them (which I concede is a common use case, there are ways around that as well).

Comment: When using this same code, it rendered a list of inputboxes but all of them had the same label with the text `Name`, and the value `prop.Name`. However, if I just render the `@prop.Name` value, it does the correct value. Any ideas?